# Understanding CloudKit limits

Tags: storage, limit, icloud, cloudkit, ckrecord

Trying to get my head around CloudKit transfer limits and it seems to be some confusion for many people.

Are records in the user's shared database counted against the user or public quota?

According to my usage in production, the requests and database storage is increasing but there shouldn't be any data within the public scope.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Records in the shared database are counted against the owner's private quota.

Answer (score 0):

[Data in the shared database counts toward your app’s iCloud storage quota.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckcontainer/1640408-sharedclouddatabase)